# Calculate RSI indicator from pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## My problem

I tried many libraries on **Github** but all of them did not produce matching results for **TradingView** so I followed the formula on this [**link**](https://school.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=technical_indicators:relative_strength_index_rsi) to calculate **RSI** indicator. I calculated it with **Excel** and collated the results with **TradingView**. I know it's **absolutely correct** but, but I didn't find a way to calculate it with **Pandas**.

## Formula

```
              100
RSI = 100 - --------
             1 + RS

RS = Average Gain / Average Loss

The very first calculations for average gain and average loss are simple
14-period averages:

First Average Gain = Sum of Gains over the past 14 periods / 14.
First Average Loss = Sum of Losses over the past 14 periods / 14

The second, and subsequent, calculations are based on the prior averages
and the current gain loss:

Average Gain = [(previous Average Gain) x 13 + current Gain] / 14.
Average Loss = [(previous Average Loss) x 13 + current Loss] / 14.
```

### Expected Results

```
     close   change     gain     loss     avg_gian    avg_loss        rs  \
0    4724.89      NaN      NaN      NaN          NaN         NaN       NaN   
1    4378.51  -346.38     0.00   346.38          NaN         NaN       NaN   
2    6463.00  2084.49  2084.49     0.00          NaN         NaN       NaN   
3    9838.96  3375.96  3375.96     0.00          NaN         NaN       NaN   
4   13716.36  3877.40  3877.40     0.00          NaN         NaN       NaN   
5   10285.10 -3431.26     0.00  3431.26          NaN         NaN       NaN   
6   10326.76    41.66    41.66     0.00          NaN         NaN       NaN   
7    6923.91 -3402.85     0.00  3402.85          NaN         NaN       NaN   
8    9246.01  2322.10  2322.10     0.00          NaN         NaN       NaN   
9    7485.01 -1761.00     0.00  1761.00          NaN         NaN       NaN   
10   6390.07 -1094.94     0.00  1094.94          NaN         NaN       NaN   
11   7730.93  1340.86  1340.86     0.00          NaN         NaN       NaN   
12   7011.21  -719.72     0.00   719.72          NaN         NaN       NaN   
13   6626.57  -384.64     0.00   384.64          NaN         NaN       NaN   
14   6371.93  -254.64     0.00   254.64   931.605000  813.959286  1.144535   
15   4041.32 -2330.61     0.00  2330.61   865.061786  922.291480  0.937948   
16   3702.90  -338.42     0.00   338.42   803.271658  880.586374  0.912201   
17   3434.10  -268.80     0.00   268.80   745.895111  836.887347  0.891273   
18   3813.69   379.59   379.59     0.00   719.730460  777.109680  0.926163   
19   4103.95   290.26   290.26     0.00   689.053999  721.601845  0.954895   
20   5320.81  1216.86  1216.86     0.00   726.754428  670.058856  1.084613   
21   8555.00  3234.19  3234.19     0.00   905.856968  622.197509  1.455899   
22  10854.10  2299.10  2299.10     0.00  1005.374328  577.754830  1.740140   

       rsi_14  
0         NaN  
1         NaN  
2         NaN  
3         NaN  
4         NaN  
5         NaN  
6         NaN  
7         NaN  
8         NaN  
9         NaN  
10        NaN  
11        NaN  
12        NaN  
13        NaN  
14  53.369848  
15  48.399038  
16  47.704239  
17  47.125561  
18  48.083322  
19  48.846358  
20  52.029461  
21  59.281719  
22  63.505515
```

## My Code

### Import

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

### Load data

```
df = pd.read_csv("rsi_14_test_data.csv")
close = df['close']
print(close)

0      4724.89
1      4378.51
2      6463.00
3      9838.96
4     13716.36
5     10285.10
6     10326.76
7      6923.91
8      9246.01
9      7485.01
10     6390.07
11     7730.93
12     7011.21
13     6626.57
14     6371.93
15     4041.32
16     3702.90
17     3434.10
18     3813.69
19     4103.95
20     5320.81
21     8555.00
22    10854.10
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

### Change

Calculate change every row

```
change = close.diff(1)
print(change)

0         NaN
1     -346.38
2     2084.49
3     3375.96
4     3877.40
5    -3431.26
6       41.66
7    -3402.85
8     2322.10
9    -1761.00
10   -1094.94
11    1340.86
12    -719.72
13    -384.64
14    -254.64
15   -2330.61
16    -338.42
17    -268.80
18     379.59
19     290.26
20    1216.86
21    3234.19
22    2299.10
Name: close, dtype: float64
```

### Gain and loss

get gain and loss from change

```
is_gain, is_loss = change > 0, change < 0
gain, loss = change, -change
gain[is_loss] = 0
loss[is_gain] = 0
​
gain.name = 'gain'
loss.name = 'loss'
print(loss)

0         NaN
1      346.38
2        0.00
3        0.00
4        0.00
5     3431.26
6        0.00
7     3402.85
8        0.00
9     1761.00
10    1094.94
11       0.00
12     719.72
13     384.64
14     254.64
15    2330.61
16     338.42
17     268.80
18       0.00
19       0.00
20       0.00
21       0.00
22       0.00
Name: loss, dtype: float64
```

### Calculate fist avg gain and loss

Mean of n prior rows

```
n = 14
avg_gain = change * np.nan
avg_loss = change * np.nan
​
avg_gain[n] = gain[:n+1].mean()
avg_loss[n] = loss[:n+1].mean()
​
avg_gain.name = 'avg_gain'
avg_loss.name = 'avg_loss'
​
avg_df = pd.concat([gain, loss, avg_gain, avg_loss], axis=1)
print(avg_df)

       gain     loss  avg_gain    avg_loss
0       NaN      NaN       NaN         NaN
1      0.00   346.38       NaN         NaN
2   2084.49     0.00       NaN         NaN
3   3375.96     0.00       NaN         NaN
4   3877.40     0.00       NaN         NaN
5      0.00  3431.26       NaN         NaN
6     41.66     0.00       NaN         NaN
7      0.00  3402.85       NaN         NaN
8   2322.10     0.00       NaN         NaN
9      0.00  1761.00       NaN         NaN
10     0.00  1094.94       NaN         NaN
11  1340.86     0.00       NaN         NaN
12     0.00   719.72       NaN         NaN
13     0.00   384.64       NaN         NaN
14     0.00   254.64   931.605  813.959286
15     0.00  2330.61       NaN         NaN
16     0.00   338.42       NaN         NaN
17     0.00   268.80       NaN         NaN
18   379.59     0.00       NaN         NaN
19   290.26     0.00       NaN         NaN
20  1216.86     0.00       NaN         NaN
21  3234.19     0.00       NaN         NaN
22  2299.10     0.00       NaN         NaN
```

The very first calculations for average gain and the average loss is ok but I don't know how to apply pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply for the second, and subsequent because they are in many rows and different columns.
It may be something like this:

```
avg_gain[n] = (avg_gain[n-1]*13 + gain[n]) / 14
```

### My Wish - My Question

- The best way to calculate and work with technical indicators?
- Complete the above code in "Pandas Style".
- Does the traditional way of coding with loops reduce performance compared to Pandas?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Well done for this nicely written question!

Comment: You are probably better off just using (or copying/pasting) the implementation from https://github.com/peerchemist/finta than reinventing the wheel

Comment: @GustavoBezerra  I don’t know why all libraries I found in Github have the same function for RSI but they didn’t produce the correct results like I did with Excel and TradingView

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The average gain and loss are calculated by a **recursive formula**, which **can't be vectorized with numpy**. We can, however, try and find an *analytical* (i.e. non-recursive) solution for calculating the individual elements. Such a solution can then be implemented using numpy. See the **Old Answer** below. I kept it just for illustrative purposes: it works well with the sample data in the OP but may suffer from numerical underflow for bigger datasets (> ~1000 rows, thanks to @WarrenNiles for pointing this problem out in the comment below).

A straightforward solution is to loop over numpy arrays (instead of looping over pandas dataframes). This can easyly be accelerated using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) by commenting out the two numba-related lines below:

```
#import numba

df['change'] = df['close'].diff()
df['gain'] = df.change.mask(df.change < 0, 0.0)
df['loss'] = -df.change.mask(df.change > 0, -0.0)

#@numba.jit
def rma(x, n):
    """Running moving average"""
    a = np.full_like(x, np.nan)
    a[n] = x[1:n+1].mean()
    for i in range(n+1, len(x)):
        a[i] = (a[i-1] * (n - 1) + x[i]) / n
    return a

df['avg_gain'] = rma(df.gain.to_numpy(), 14)
df['avg_loss'] = rma(df.loss.to_numpy(), 14)

df['rs'] = df.avg_gain / df.avg_loss
df['rsi'] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df.rs))
```

For the 3173-rows TSLA dataset linked in the comment below, it takes on my machine:

- 2 s for the [pandas loop solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57008625/3944322)
- 23 ms for this array loop solution without numba
- 4 ms for this array loop solution with numba

---

**Old Answer**

Denoting the average gain as `y` and the current gain as `x`, we get `y[i] = a*y[i-1] + b*x[i]`, where `a = 13/14` and `b = 1/14` for `n = 14`. Unwrapping the recursion leads to:
[image]
(sorry for the picture, was just to cumbersome to type it)

This can be efficiently calculated in numpy using `cumsum` (rma = running moving average):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'close':[4724.89, 4378.51,6463.00,9838.96,13716.36,10285.10,
                          10326.76,6923.91,9246.01,7485.01,6390.07,7730.93,
                          7011.21,6626.57,6371.93,4041.32,3702.90,3434.10,
                          3813.69,4103.95,5320.81,8555.00,10854.10]})
n = 14


def rma(x, n, y0):
    a = (n-1) / n
    ak = a**np.arange(len(x)-1, -1, -1)
    return np.r_[np.full(n, np.nan), y0, np.cumsum(ak * x) / ak / n + y0 * a**np.arange(1, len(x)+1)]

df['change'] = df['close'].diff()
df['gain'] = df.change.mask(df.change < 0, 0.0)
df['loss'] = -df.change.mask(df.change > 0, -0.0)
df['avg_gain'] = rma(df.gain[n+1:].to_numpy(), n, np.nansum(df.gain.to_numpy()[:n+1])/n)
df['avg_loss'] = rma(df.loss[n+1:].to_numpy(), n, np.nansum(df.loss.to_numpy()[:n+1])/n)
df['rs'] = df.avg_gain / df.avg_loss
df['rsi_14'] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df.rs))
```

Output of `df.round(2)`:

```
         close   change     gain     loss  avg_gain  avg_loss    rs    rsi  rsi_14
0      4724.89      NaN      NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
1      4378.51  -346.38     0.00   346.38       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
2      6463.00  2084.49  2084.49     0.00       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
3      9838.96  3375.96  3375.96     0.00       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
4     13716.36  3877.40  3877.40     0.00       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
5     10285.10 -3431.26     0.00  3431.26       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
6     10326.76    41.66    41.66     0.00       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
7      6923.91 -3402.85     0.00  3402.85       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
8      9246.01  2322.10  2322.10     0.00       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
9      7485.01 -1761.00     0.00  1761.00       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
10     6390.07 -1094.94     0.00  1094.94       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
11     7730.93  1340.86  1340.86     0.00       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
12     7011.21  -719.72     0.00   719.72       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
13     6626.57  -384.64     0.00   384.64       NaN       NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN
14     6371.93  -254.64     0.00   254.64    931.61    813.96  1.14  53.37   53.37
15     4041.32 -2330.61     0.00  2330.61    865.06    922.29  0.94  48.40   48.40
16     3702.90  -338.42     0.00   338.42    803.27    880.59  0.91  47.70   47.70
17     3434.10  -268.80     0.00   268.80    745.90    836.89  0.89  47.13   47.13
18     3813.69   379.59   379.59     0.00    719.73    777.11  0.93  48.08   48.08
19     4103.95   290.26   290.26     0.00    689.05    721.60  0.95  48.85   48.85
20     5320.81  1216.86  1216.86     0.00    726.75    670.06  1.08  52.03   52.03
21     8555.00  3234.19  3234.19     0.00    905.86    622.20  1.46  59.28   59.28
22    10854.10  2299.10  2299.10     0.00   1005.37    577.75  1.74  63.51   63.51
```

Concerning your last question about performance: **explicite loops in python / pandas are terrible, avoid them whenever you can**. If you can't, try [cython or numba](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html).

Comment: This does not cover two important edge cases:

1. When there is no avg_loss over the timeperiod you have a DIV/0
2. When ak in function rma() line 2 results in a division by 0.

Try a 3 day RSI using TSLA downloaded from yahoo finance daily data. Given this is a financial data algorithm this is a big problem as a general solution.

Comment: ``` 
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  return np.r_[np.full(n, np.nan), y0, np.cumsum(ak * x) / ak / n + y0 * a**np.arange(1, len(x)+1)]
```

Comment: again it might work with linspace but it still throws the error with real data. I would look into it as the values are wrong.

Comment: Try a 3 day RSI using TSLA close data downloaded from yahoo finance daily data. Look at the result. Easier to download that then type out everything.
Try the following link: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/TSLA?period1=1277769600&period2=1675641600&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true
But YahooFinance can get finicky so I would try downloading it yourself.

Comment: @WarrenNiles: Thanks for sharing the dataset. It updated my answer. The issue with the original numpy solution was not division by zero but numerical underflow, i.e. the power becomes smaller than the smallest possible floating point number (you can see it if you turn the warning into an error by `np.seterr('raise')`)

Answer (score 8):

There is an easier way, the package talib.

```
import talib   
close = df['close']
rsi = talib.RSI(close, timeperiod=14)
```

If you'd like Bollinger Bands to go with your RSI that is easy too.

```
upperBB, middleBB, lowerBB = talib.BBANDS(close, timeperiod=20, nbdevup=2, nbdevdn=2, matype=0)
```

You can use Bollinger Bands on RSI instead of the fixed reference levels of 70 and 30.

```
upperBBrsi, MiddleBBrsi, lowerBBrsi = talib.BBANDS(rsi, timeperiod=50, nbdevup=2, nbdevdn=2, matype=0)
```

Finally, you can normalize RSI using the %b calcification.

```
normrsi = (rsi - lowerBBrsi) / (upperBBrsi - lowerBBrsi)
```

info on talib
https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/

info on Bollinger Bands
https://www.BollingerBands.com

Comment: The TA-lib does not give the corresponding values by tradingview

Comment: @Justme talib's and TradingView's RSIs match perfectly for me. Perhaps there is a small difference in the two data sets you used to generate the indicator?  What nobody has pointed out is that the answers here are incorrect as they do not use the unique smoothing method Welles Wilder specified for RSI. You can see the proper method in his book: https://www.amazon.com/New-Concepts-Technical-Trading-Systems/dp/0894590278

Comment: Hi John, I runned a unittest and indeed tablib is giving corresponding values. The unittest is based on xls sheet from https://school.stockcharts.com/doku.php?id=technical_indicators:relative_strength_index_rsi.  But then again comparing to tradingview I see different value (e.g. tradingview has 47,15 and talib gives 46,79). So is tradingview using Welles Wilders smoothing method?

Comment: Cannot uno my - vote, only if you edit it with a dot i can undo the vote...

Comment: @Justme It appears that the TV calc is incorrect. I find this hard to believe as I hold their platform in high regard. However, I have checked against three sources: AmiBroker, eSignal and TradeNavigator all of which agree. Perhaps I am missing something, in any case I will drop them a note.

Comment: any news, i run several other pyhton code in orde to see the match with TV but did not succeed..

Comment: The folks at TV are looking into it, not answer yet. By the by, I did edit my answer as you requested.

Comment: Thxs, I upvoted it as it is correct related to the question. Hope to hear from you of the TV guys.

Comment: Please update when TV people answer, I have the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option.

I will be touching only on your second bullet

```
# libraries required
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'close':[4724.89, 4378.51,6463.00,9838.96,13716.36,10285.10,
                          10326.76,6923.91,9246.01,7485.01,6390.07,7730.93,
                          7011.21,6626.57,6371.93,4041.32,3702.90,3434.10,
                          3813.69,4103.95,5320.81,8555.00,10854.10]})

df['change'] = df['close'].diff(1) # Calculate change

# calculate gain / loss from every change
df['gain'] = np.select([df['change']>0, df['change'].isna()], 
                       [df['change'], np.nan], 
                       default=0) 
df['loss'] = np.select([df['change']<0, df['change'].isna()], 
                       [-df['change'], np.nan], 
                       default=0)

# create avg_gain /  avg_loss columns with all nan
df['avg_gain'] = np.nan 
df['avg_loss'] = np.nan

n = 14 # what is the window

# keep first occurrence of rolling mean
df['avg_gain'][n] = df['gain'].rolling(window=n).mean().dropna().iloc[0] 
df['avg_loss'][n] = df['loss'].rolling(window=n).mean().dropna().iloc[0]
# Alternatively
df['avg_gain'][n] = df.loc[:n, 'gain'].mean()
df['avg_loss'][n] = df.loc[:n, 'loss'].mean()

# This is not a pandas way, looping through the pandas series, but it does what you need
for i in range(n+1, df.shape[0]):
    df['avg_gain'].iloc[i] = (df['avg_gain'].iloc[i-1] * (n - 1) + df['gain'].iloc[i]) / n
    df['avg_loss'].iloc[i] = (df['avg_loss'].iloc[i-1] * (n - 1) + df['loss'].iloc[i]) / n

# calculate rs and rsi
df['rs'] = df['avg_gain'] / df['avg_loss']
df['rsi'] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df['rs'] ))
```

Comment: **I think this part:**
`df['avg_gain'][n] = df['gain'].rolling(window=n).mean().dropna().iloc[0] `
**should be:**

`avg_gain[n] = gain[:n+1].mean()`

**Because for large DataFrame, rolling, mean and dropnan  around DataFrame only to calculate 1 value is wasteful. But basically, your code works very well. Thanks**

Comment: `avg_gain[n] = gain[:n+1].mean()` is wrong, it must be avg_gain[n] = gain[:n].mean()`. **Contrary to usual python slices, both the start and the stop are included in pandas slices, when present in the index**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the RSI of a time series using native pandas calls, you can use the following one-line code:

```
    n=14
df['rsi14'] = 100 - (100 / (1 + df['Close'].diff(1).mask(df['Close'].diff(1) < 0, 0).ewm(alpha=1/n, adjust=False).mean() / df['Close'].diff(1).mask(df['Close'].diff(1) > 0, -0.0).abs().ewm(alpha=1/n, adjust=False).mean()))
```

And it's eave faster than numpy results (ms / loop):

```
rows    np      loop    native
23      1.0     1.3     0.8
230     1.1     1.4     0.9
2300    1.1     1.3     0.9
23000   3.4     1.8     1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the rsi code, replace every thing that has "aa":

```
import pandas as pd
rsi_period = 14
df = pd.Series(coinaalist)
chg = df.diff(1)
gain = chg.mask(chg<0,0)
loss = chg.mask(chg>0,0)
avg_gain = gain.ewm(com = rsi_period-1,min_periods=rsi_period).mean()
avg_loss = loss.ewm(com = rsi_period-1,min_periods=rsi_period).mean()
rs = abs(avg_gain / avg_loss)
crplaa = 100 - (100/(1+rs))
coinaarsi = crplaa.iloc[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave +1 to lepi, however his formula can be made even more pandorable:

```
n = 14
df['rsi14'] = df['Close'].diff(1).mask(df['Close'].diff(1) < 0, 0).ewm(alpha=1/n, adjust=False).mean().div(df['Close'].diff(1).mask(df['Close'].diff(1) > 0, -0.0).abs().ewm(alpha=1/n, adjust=False).mean()).add(1).rdiv(100).rsub(100)
```

so `div()` was used instead of `/` and `add(1).rdiv(100).rsub(100)` instead of `+ - /` in other places.

Comment: Please explain why this is better than lepis answer