# Calculate RSI indicator according to TradingView

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I struggle to manually calculate RSI indicator via python.

The formula is explained [here](https://www.tradingview.com/ideas/relativestrengthindex/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006437/calculate-rsi-indicator-from-pandas-dataframe).

I tried many answers here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634503/12260544) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400434/12260544) give me the same result but different from the value displayed on TradingView. Below is my implementation of these answers.

```
#price change from Sep 17 to 15 days ago
delta = pd.Series([1.5, -0.9, 1.6, -1.8, -1.9, -0.3, 0.3, -1.1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, -0.9, 2.0, 1.2, -1.9, ])
delta = delta[::-1] #reverse result Sep 3 -> Sep17 list
period = 14 #calculate RSI 14
gain = delta.clip(lower=0)
loss = delta.clip(upper=0).abs()
gain_avg = gain.ewm(alpha=1 / period).mean()
loss_avg = loss.ewm(alpha=1 / period).mean()
rsi = np.where(gain_avg == 0, 0, np.where(loss_avg == 0, 100, 100 - (100 / (1 + gain_avg / loss_avg))))
```

Result

```
array([ 0.        , 40.48192897, 65.52871773, 54.42860064, 57.04085224,
       62.44962094, 66.93315247, 55.68193396, 57.76701673, 54.98126804,
       41.37316127, 33.03207836, 43.86550257, 39.95053047, 48.2417529 ])
```

The RSI on Sep 17 calculated is `48.2` while the one show on TradingView is `51.51` ([source](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/4kgvh6qh/))

I also tried some manual calculations which results `69.13`:

```
def Avg_EMA_cal(alpha_, t, gain_or_loss):
    if t == 0:
        return gain_or_loss[t]
    return alpha_ * gain_or_loss[t] + (1 - alpha_) * Avg_EMA_cal(alpha_, t - 1, gain_or_loss)


alpha = 1 / period
avg_up_ema = Avg_EMA_cal(alpha, N, gain)
avg_down_ema = Avg_EMA_cal(alpha, N, loss)

rs_ema = avg_up_ema / avg_down_ema
rsi_ema = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs_ema)
```

These are really making me dizzy, both the formula and numerical precision.

Comment: I give it `(period * 4) + 1` data points instead of `period` data points. I'm not asking you to change your `alpha`. The `+ 1` is used for creating the `delta`. The `* 4` is used for bootstrapping `ewm`. This won't get you a perfect match with TradingView, but will get you a lot closer.